# How to accurately filter the cpu Usage by process on grafana

Tags: windows, grafana, promql

Actually I'm using this query but im getting weird numbers:

```
((sum(irate(windows_process_cpu_time_total{job="job", instance="instance", process!="Idle"}[$interval]))
    by (process, process_id) 
    / ignoring(process, process_id) group_left sum(windows_cs_logical_processors)
) * 100)
```

But its not giving the correct percentage on 0-100 range or 0-1 range
[CPU BY PROCESS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJFIV.png)